# python replace values by searching dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a freshman in python. Recently, I met a really simple  question.First,there is a dictionary which has abbreviation of words,such as:

```
{'a':apple,'b':bread,'c':coke}
```

Also, there is a dataframe, whose index is `{'a','b','c'}` and I want replace the index by searching the dictionary.So the result will be

```
{'apple','bread','coke'}
```

In fact,I know I can use circulation by visiting every item.However,this method can be terrible for the huge data.

So I'd like to know if there any other efficient ways I can use?

Comment: In order to replace each item you'll need to visit each item. There is no getting around that. Just make sure that each replacement operation takes a constant amount of time (if you're using set and dict then you're fine)

Comment: apple, bread, coke are strings I guess?

Comment: yes, they are all string.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to visit every element if you wish to replace them with something else. Here's an idea on how you can achieve it in python.

Assuming your dataset looks something like this:

```
d = {'a':'apple', 'b': 'bread', 'c':'coke'}
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can do something like this using list comprehension:

```
# look in the dictionary for the value, 
# if it's there replace with the value, else let it be there as it is

l = [d[e] if e in d else e for e in l]
```

or using map:

```
l = map(lambda e: d[e] if e in d else e, l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a way of replacing values without iterating over the elements but if you want to keep your code simple, you can try something like this:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'apple','b': 'bread' ,'c':'coke'}
auxList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

auxList = [dict1.get(elem) for elem in auxList]

print(auxList)
```

The result is:

```
['apple', 'bread', 'coke']
```

or you can try:

```
auxList = list(map(lambda elem: dict1.get(elem), auxList))
```

The result will be again:

```
['apple', 'bread', 'coke']
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer with panda's DataFrame -

```
import pandas as pd

a = ['a','b','c']
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=a, data=b)   
dic = {'a':'apple','b':'bread','c':'coke'}
df
   0  1  2
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9
```

Getting the dictionary values by the dataframe index:

```
[dic.get(a) for a in df.index]
['apple', 'bread', 'coke']
```

Set index:

```
df.set_index(keys=[[dic.get(a) for a in df.index]], inplace=True)
df
       0  1  2
apple  1  2  3
bread  4  5  6
coke   7  8  9
```